# Could you tell me why jquery settimeout doesnt work with ajax keyup event

Tags: jquery

My question about setTimeout in my html code i use ajax with jquery again and my code  .And i use primefaces jsf . Why am i using jquery settimeout with ajax keyup event

This is my jquery code and its now working but when i add settimeout its not working.

```
$ = jQuery;

$(document).ready(function()  
{
    setTimeout(function()
    {
        refreshHook();
    },1000)

});


function refreshHook()
{
    $(".numberonly").keydown(function(event) 
    {  
        // Allow: backspace, delete, tab and escape
        if ( event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode==190 || event.keyCode == 9 || event.keyCode == 27 || 

        // Allow: Ctrl+A
        (event.keyCode == 65 && event.ctrlKey === true) || 

        // Allow: home, end, left, right
        (event.keyCode >= 35 && event.keyCode <= 39)) {

        // let it happen, don't do anything
        return;
    }
    else 
    {
        // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
        if (  event.shiftKey|| (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57) && (event.keyCode < 96 || event.keyCode > 105 ) ) 
        {
            event.preventDefault(); 
        } 
    }

   });
  }
```

This is my html code.

```
<p:fieldset legend="Fieldset" style="background-color: lightsteelblue" >
    <h:panelGrid columns="5">
    <strong>LandAmoutn(Ha):</strong>
    <p:inputText id="spinner1" type="text" styleClass="numberonly"  value="#{carbonController.model.meyvebahcesidikimi}"  style="background-color: lightgrey" >
    <p:ajax event="keyup" process="@this" update="birdikim"  listener="#{carbonController.doMeyveBahcesiDikimHesabı}"/>

    </p:inputText>
    <p:row><strong>=</strong></p:row>
    <p:inputText id="birdikim" value="#{carbonController.model.meyvebahcesidikimsonuc}" readonly="true" style="background-color:lightgrey">
    <f:convertNumber integerOnly="true"/>
    </p:inputText>
    <p:row><strong>Mg C/Ha</strong></p:row>
    </h:panelGrid>
</p:fieldset>
```

Can anybody tell me where is my mistake. i spent a lot of times.I want to send my images but stackoverflow doenst allow to send :)

Comment: Also, are you referencing the jQuery library?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Being honest that `setTimeout` there is useless. If what you want is to attach `keydown` event for future elements you should take a look at [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/). Having said that, [please clarify your question](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: Yeah, you should use .on() like this:
$('body').on('keydown', 'numberonly', function() {});
You can use body or any other parent selector.

Comment: Same problem with `window.setTimeout` ? Is `refreshHook` in global scope? If it is just the one function with no args you don't need to wrap it. `window.setTimeout(refreshHook,1000)`

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(refreshHook, 1000);
});
```

This appears to be working http://jsfiddle.net/cQjmx/5/

**EDIT** - Not sure if this is what you were after, but as nobody else has posted anything give this a go http://jsfiddle.net/cQjmx/37/

Comment: i want to see result in id="birdikim" after 3 seconds . And also i use ajax in myproject . when user enter number automatically updating result but i want to see result after 3 seconds . İ hope i its clear. thx for interest

Comment: well all of your code and the fixed code in my post is going to do is allow any input to that text box for the first second of $(document).ready().

Comment: sorry i dont understand . Pete . Problem is setTimeout

Comment: @RustyUmt, Pete is saying the element exists by the time the document is _ready_ and therefore deferring `refreshHook` means there is a small time where you can type without restriction into that element before `refreshHook` is executed.

Comment: @RustyUmt Check my recent edit, it seems to do what you were looking for (although you will need to hook your ajax up to it)

Comment: Pete it doesnt work . I think problem is ajax keyup i didnt use with   jquery settimeout .I try alot of thinks and i m really bored .I hope you understand what i m talking about .

Comment: @RustyUmt can you tell me exactly what isn't working? Does the fiddle I posted work for you? Does it do what you wanted to (other than the ajax)? If you can post a link to it not working, or a snippet of code where it is failing that might help